# How to use nautilus to connect to a remote server: 2 features missing?

Tags: nautilus, ftp

I've recently discovered that I can connect myself to a web server using nautilus (so I don't need stuff like winscp).

So I did manage to connect myself to my web server, and started to download some files.
But I've found a couple of things missing:

**How do I know when it finished? And how many files did already copy?**

**And how do I go to a higher folder level than the one that it is opened by default? There's no "upper" arrow as in ftp programs.**

I've tried several, quite a lot ftp programs and I love winscp (which I couldn't make it work with wine, by the way), so the thing that's quite close to the easy way of winscp is nautilus.

Is there a way to do achieve two things? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When copying files, even from a network location, Nautilus should open a popup window showing the file copying progress, and when it should finish etc *(if one does not appear, it likely has been small enough to copy over quickly)*:
[image]

To navigate up a directory, just press the location button for the directory on the top bar - you may also be able to use <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Up</kbd> or similar.
[image]